# PHP no registra en la DB MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Al querer insertar datos en MYSQL, el código de PHP no lo hace. Traté de basarme en otro código que realiza la misma acción, para ver si veia el error, pero no lo pude encontrar de ninguna manera.

(Los datos provienen de un formulario)

guardar.php

```
<?php

    include("con_db.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if  (strlen($_POST['nombre'])     >= 1 && 
            strlen($_POST['apellido'])   >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['telefono'])   >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['mail'])       >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['dni'])        >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['nacimiento']) >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['domicilio'])  >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['localidad'])  >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['provincia'])  >= 1 &&
            strlen($_POST['cp'])         >= 1) {

                $fecareg    = date("d/m/y");
                $nombre     = trim($_POST['nombre']);
                $apellido   = trim($_POST['apellido']);
                $telefono   = trim($_POST['telefono']);
                $mail       = trim($_POST['mail']);
                $dni        = trim($_POST['dni']);
                $nacimiento = trim($_POST['nacimiento']);
                $domicilio  = trim($_POST['domicilio']);
                $localidad  = trim($_POST['localidad']);
                $provincia  = trim($_POST['provincia']);
                $cp         = trim($_POST['cp']);
                $consulta   = "INSERT INTO pacientes(id, fecareg, nombre, apellido, telefono, mail, nacimiento, dni, domicilio, localidad, provincia, cp) VALUES ('$facareg','$nombre','$apellido','$telefono','$mail','$dni','$nacimiento','$domicilio','$localidad','$provincia','$cp')";
                $resultado  = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);

                if ($resultado) {
                    ?>
                        <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=../index.html">
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                        <h3 class="bad">Ups ha ocurrido un error</h3>
                    <?php
                }
        } else {
            ?>
                <h3 class="bad">Completa los campos</h3>
            <?php
        }
    }

?>
```

con_db.php

```
<?php

    $conex = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345!!", "excel");

?>
```

Comment: Hola! Harían falta dos cosas importantes para responder. Una que en tu archivo `error.log`  y ver que aparece y lo siguiente que nos facilites el formulario.

Comment: Parece un error tipográfico `... VALUES ('$facareg','$nombre', ---)` solo revisa el nombre de cada variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. fijate si realmente funciono la conexion a la bd

   ```
   $enlace = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

   if (!$enlace) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
   }
   ```
2. revisa la consulta para ver si no hay error de sintaxis

esto se ve raro

```
$consulta   = "INSERT INTO pacientes(id, fecareg, nombre, apellido, telefono, mail, nacimiento, dni, domicilio, localidad, provincia, cp) VALUES ('$facareg','$nombre','$apellido','$telefono','$mail','$dni','$nacimiento','$domicilio','$localidad','$provincia','$cp')";
```

deberia algo asi

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tabla (column 1, column2) VALUES ('".$_POST['value1']."', '".$_POST['value2']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba que la conexión sea exitosa, seguido de que tu consulta lo haría de esta manera.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345!!', 'excel') or die (mysql_error($mysqli));

    $nombre = '';
    $apellido = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pacientes (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')") or die($mysqli->error);

header("location: index.php");

}
```